# Милые слова наподобие «умничка», «солнышко», «зайка»

Tags: лексика

Скажите, пожалуйста, какие есть милые слова вроде **«умничка», «солнышко», «зайка»?**

Чем больше, тем лучше.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Милые" слова в науке называются мелиоративами (от лат. *melioratio* — улучшение), они выражают положительную, ласкательную эмоционально-экспрессивную оценку кого-, чего-либо: соседушка, золотце, кисонька — и противопоставлены пейоративам (лат. *pejor* — худший), выражающим отрицательную, уничижительную эмоционально-экспрессивную оценку (гадёныш, тупица, [выпятить] глазища).

Вы можете образовать сколько угодно подобных "милых" слов сами, зная, что они образуются путем прибавления суффиксов –чик–/–ик–, –ишк–, –енк– (–еньк–), –к–, –очк–/–ечк– и проч. к основам слов: птица — птич**к**а, заяц — зай**чик**, лукошко — лукош**ечк**о, Михаил — м**ишк**а, сокол — сокол**ик**, вишня — виш**енк**а и т. д.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!